# How to Access yii2 relation map table fields

Tags: php, relational-database, yii2

I have three table that names is 'agency' , 'property' and 'property_agency_map'

**agency** table :

```
--------------------------
| id => primary key ...  |
| name => string ...     |
| and som more fields    |
--------------------------
```

**property** table :

```
--------------------------
| id => primary key ...  |
| state => string ...    |
| adress => string ...   |
| and som more fields    |
--------------------------
```

**property_agency_map** table :

```
------------------------------
| id => primary key ...      |
| agency_id => string ...    |
| property_id => string ...  |
| status =>  intiger ...     |
| favorite =>  intiger ...   |
------------------------------
```

the **property_agency_map** table connect **agency** table to **property** table.

agency model :

```
 public function getProperties(){
    return $this->hasMany(Property::className(),['id'=>'property_id'])
        ->viaTable('"{{%property_agency_map}}"',['agency_id'=>'id']);
}
```

Now My question is How to access 'favorite' and 'status' field in **property_agency_map** ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create new method to get property_agency_map items for agency:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class PropertyAgencyMap extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the name of the table associated with this ActiveRecord class.
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'property_agency_map';
    }
}

class Agency extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the name of the table associated with this ActiveRecord class.
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'agency';
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPropertyAgency()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PropertyAgencyMap::className(), ['agency_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have PropertyAgencyMap Model !

Comment: Why don't to create it?